# Move specific overlayitem to top

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a class that extends `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>` to put 200 markers on a `MapView`.
Now I want 1 specific marker to always be on top of the others.

How would I do this?

This is how I add the markers to the overlay:

```
boolean isTopMarker;
for (Location location : locationList) {
    isTopMarker = location.getTitle().equals("MyMarker");
    markerOverlay.addOverlayItem(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getTitle(), isTopMarker);
}
markerOverlay.moveTopMarkerToTop();
```

The methods in the `MarkerOverlay` class:

```
@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem, boolean isTopMarker) {
    if (isTopMarker) {
        Drawable markerDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_top);
        boundCenterBottom(markerDrawable);
        overlayItem.setMarker(markerDrawable);
        topMarkerOverlayItem = overlayItem;
    }
    mOverlays.add(overlayItem);
    populate();
}

public void addOverlayItem(double latitude, double longitude, String title, boolean isTopMarker) {
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1000000), (int) (longitude * 1000000));
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title, null);
    addOverlayItem(overlayItem, isTopMarker);
}

public void moveTopMarkerToTop(){
    if(topMarkerOverlayItem != null){
        //What to do here?
    }
}
```

I've tried to reassing a marker `Drawable` to the `topMarkerOverlayItem`, that didn't work. I also tried to remove and add the `topMarkerOverlayItem` to the list of `OverlayItem`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make an extra `ItemizedOverlay` for your special Marker, and add this `ItemizedOverlay` at the end of the `MapView.getOverlays()` List. `MapView` will traverse through all `Overlays` starting from 0 to Overlays.count(). This Way your Special Overlay should be drawn as last one and is therefore always on top!